# Multiple App Layouts in Marionette

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

We have a Marionette App (2.4.4).

It currently contains a bunch of top level regions (header, nav, content etc).

I now need to add some pages that do not use these regions.  I could wire in a load of events to check when certain pages are shown and then hide / show regions, but I was wondering if there is a simple way to define multiple App Layouts, and then have routes define which layout to load up?

So layout A would have the header, nav, content  and layout B would just have header and content.

Then some routes use A and some routes use B?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  In v2.x Application has multiple regions.. and so I suspect your top level regions are defined on the application.. in v3 application now only has a single region..

I would suggest modifying your app such that there is a single application region.. and put your top level layouts inside of it, instead of using your application as a layout.

This way you can swap out layouts as need be per the route, and you're on your way to being able to upgrade.

Comment: ah ok..   At the moment, when a controller for a sub module wants to show it's view, it calls `App.main.show(View);`   `main` being the main content region.    So, if we have 2 top level `LayoutViews` would we instantiate them, and then make them available to the controllers?  And then the controller would somehow show one of the layouts, and then show its main view inside it?     My concern is re rendering / loosing state of the nav items in one of the layouts if each sub module re loads the top level layout, if that makes sense...

Comment: I would suggest storing state externally from the view so you can rebuild it.  But it'd essentially be `App.main.show(new MainLayout({ state: storedState }));`   A lesser option would be to `preventDestroy` the layout from the main region to keep untouched.. but that's certainly not ideal.  In this scenario.. `main` would be the only region on the Application.. and any other regions would be part of that.